# Can I return a value from a dictionary if the input value is in a set?

Tags: python

Using Python 3.8.1

New programmer, so forgive me if the jargon's a bit off. I'm currently working on a learning exercise from a book where the intent is to take a user's input and return a tuple with the part of speech the user's input matches (eg "go" would return ("verb","go")). I set up an if-then structure that *works*, but I'm wondering if I can instead use a dictionary to accomplish the same end while making it so adding new categories would be simpler (instead of adding a set and a tree in the if-then, I can just create a dictionary entry).

Part of the idea is if the user's input is not in a set of keywords I want to return an error, so using something like dict.get() isn't exactly what I want here as I don't want a null value to be returned.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I'm looking for some way where I can feed a function a string and have that function return the key value of a dictionary where the string is in the key's associated set. More verbosely, if I have this dictionary:

```py
lexicon = {
    'direction': {'east','south','north','west'}
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```py
lexicon.???('south') == 'direction'
```

Where ??? is a function that I don't know if it exists or not.

---

Here's what I currently have:

```py
directions = {'north','south','east','west'}
verbs = {'go','kill','eat'}
stops = {'the','in','of'}
nouns = {'bear','princess'}

def scan(input_string):
    words = input_string.split()
    result = []

    for word in words:
        if word in directions:
            result.append(('direction', word))
        elif word in verbs:
            result.append(('verb', word))
        elif word in stops:
            result.append(('stop', word))
        elif word in nouns:
            result.append(('noun', word))
        else:
            try:
                word = int(word)
                result.append(('number',word))
            except:
                result.append(('error',word))

    return result
```

Comment: You *can* use a dictionary, like you asked - just google 'Python dictionary' and it should be pretty self-evident; if you have any issues with your code once you switch your code over to it, feel free to come ask about it. You can also do stuff like `if "key" in some_dict:` to detect if your key is missing.

Comment: I'm still struggling with how to return a key if an input is inside a set. Eg, if I have this as my dictionary:

```
lexicon = {
    'direction':{'north','south','east','west'},
    'verb':{'go','kill','eat'},
    'stop':{'the','in','of'},
    'noun':{'bear','princess'}
}
```
How do I get 'direction' if I input 'east'?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I added some clarification in the OP, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty simple actually, but maybe not intuitive to a new coder. First make the dict of categories and associated words, then simply lookup each word while keeping track of the category label.

```
categories = {
    'direction': {'north', 'south', 'east', 'west'},
    'verb': {'go', 'kill', 'eat'},
    'conjunction': {'the', 'in', 'of'},
    'noun': {'bear', 'princess'},
    }

...
for category, wordset in categories.items():
    if word in wordset:
        result.append((category, word))
```

---

BTW, you can simplify `scan` by putting the categorization into a function, and you can improve a few other things:

```
def categorize(word):
    for category, wordset in categories.items():
        if word in wordset:
            return (category, word)

    try:
        word = int(word)  # Keep the try-block slim
    except ValueError:  # Bare "except" is bad practice
        return ('error', word)
    else:
        return ('number', word)

def scan(phrase):
    # Use a list comprehension instead of a bunch of appending
    return [categorize(word) for word in phrase.split()]

print(scan('go north princess'))
# -> [('verb', 'go'), ('direction', 'north'), ('noun', 'princess')]
print(scan('5 steps'))
# -> [('number', '5'), ('error', 'steps')]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you! This is definitely the other way around from how I was thinking about it initially but it works like a charm.

Comment: @Martin Welcome. You're right, you could actually do it the other way around, i.e. have a dict with word-category pairs, then `dict[word]` to get the category but catch `KeyError`. That would be much faster if you had a lot of categories. The only tricky part is building the dict since you wouldn't want to type each word's category manually. You could flip it like this: `{word: cat for cat in categories for word in categories[cat]}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an assertion in order to check if the user wrote these keywords or it was something else. Here's a link that can be useful: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second argument of dict.get() to return a response in case the key is not in the dict. Setting to False you can reduce your decision tree:

```
data_dict = {'directions': [], 'verbs': [], ...}

if word in data_dict.get('direction', False):
    result.append(('direction', word))
```

Combine with a external for to iterate the keys in the dictionary (with data_dict.keys()) so you can reduce it ever more!

Answer (score 0):

Label the terms with their category

```
directions = {'north','south','east','west'}
verbs = {'go','kill','eat'}
stops = {'the','in','of'}
nouns = {'bear','princess'}

ctgs = (
    'directions',
    'verbs',
    'stops',
    'nouns'
)

vals = (
    directions,
    verbs,
    stops,
    nouns
)
d = {v: c for c, vc in zip(ctgs, vals) for v in vc}

def scan(input_string):
    words = input_string.split()
    result = []

    for word in words:
        ctg = d.get(word)
        if ctg is not None:
            result.append((ctg, word))
        else:
            try:
                word = int(word)
                result.append(('number',word))
            except ValueError:
                result.append(('error',word))

    return result

s = 'go west 3 jump'
print(scan(s))
```

produces

```
[('verbs', 'go'), ('directions', 'west'), ('number', 3), ('error', 'jump')]
```